# Rails locals in nested partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index.html.erb file with this line:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/object_grid', locals: { items: @cars, item_type: 'Car', show_versions: true } %>
```

I then have an object_grid partial like so:

```
<div class="object-grid" data-object="<%= item_type.downcase %>" data-infinitescroll-target="grid">
    <%= render partial: "#{item_type.downcase.pluralize}/#{item_type.to_s.downcase}", collection: items, locals: { show_versions: show_versions } %>
</div>
```

I then have a car partial that does some output but importantly has the following conditional in it:

```
<% if car.has_versions? && show_versions %>
  // Show version details here
<% end %>
```

The area where the version details should be showing is not being output.

The object_grid partial has the following error:

> _object_grid.html.erb where line #2 raised:
>
> undefined local variable or method `show_versions' for
> #ActionView::Base:0x000000006d4d40

Any ideas?

If I do `<%= show_versions %>` above the render partial line in object_grid then I see the output of "true", but it fails on the render line.

I'm really confused.

Can you please help?

Comment: since you are passing it down another level you need to do a little more work. add this to the top of your object_grid partial `<%
show_versions = local_assigns.has_key?(:show_versions) ? show_versions : false %>`